# The centroid ,circumcentre and orthocentre for any triangle are collinear.

Tags: geometry

The Euler Line is easy to demonstrate by construction but find it rather to prove by co-ordinate geometry means.Does such a proof exist.

Answer (score 0):

We can embed our triangle in $\mathbb{C}$ and assume without loss of generality that $R=1$, $O=0$ and
$$ A=e^{i\theta_A},\quad B=e^{i\theta_B},\quad C=e^{i\theta_C}.$$
With these choices, the centroid $G$ lies in:
$$ G=\frac{1}{3}\left(e^{i\theta_A}+e^{i\theta_B}+e^{i\theta_C}\right), $$
so we just need to prove that the orthocenter $H$ lies in:
$$ H=\lambda\left(e^{i\theta_A}+e^{i\theta_B}+e^{i\theta_C}\right) $$
for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$. If we simply try $\lambda=1$ we can notice that:
$$ H-A = \left(\cos\theta_B+\cos\theta_C\right)+i\left(\sin\theta_B+\sin\theta_C\right),$$
$$ B-C = \left(\cos\theta_B-\cos\theta_C\right)+i\left(\sin\theta_B-\sin\theta_C\right),$$
and $i\frac{H-A}{B-C}$ belongs to $\mathbb{R}$, so $AH$ is orthogonal to $BC$, and it is straightforward to check, through the same argument, that $BH$ is orthogonal to $AC$. Hence the choice $\lambda=1$ really leads to the orthocenter and we have proved the Euler theorem.